# How to concatenate word, with line break in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have a multiline string, for example:

```
"The wolverine is now es-
sentially absent from 
the southern end
of its European range."
```

What I want is: remove hyphen and concatenate word in previous line.
Result, should be like:

```
"The wolverine is now essentially
absent from  
the southern end
of its European range."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need:

`string.gsub(/(-\n)(\S+)\s/) { "#{$2} \n" }`

This code will remove the `-\n` to join the word "essentially" and will add `\n` after it, return your desire result:

"The wolverine is now essentially \nabsent from \nthe southern end\nof its European range.\n"

Answer (score 4):

Try something like

```
new_string = string.gsub("-\n", "")
```

This will remove all dashes followed by `\n`, which indicates a new line

Comment: To be on the safe side, maybe `s.gsub(/(?<=[[:alpha:]])-\s*\n\s*/,"")`.

Comment: It's good to be a bit lax here. Trailing spaces happen frequently by accident.

Comment: If the regex is `r = /(?<=[[:alpha:]])-\s*\n\s*/`, `"The wolf is es- \n sentially".gsub(r,'')  #=>  "The wolverine is now essentially"` and `"111-222-\n3333".gsub(r,'') #=> "111-222-\n3333"` (break is retained). `(?<=[[:alpha:]])` is a positive lookbehind that requires the hyphen to be preceded by a letter.

Comment: This solution will also remove the `"\n"` after `-`. Not sure if it's what he wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Don't seems to be the most optimized solution, but it will work in most of cases:

```
text = "The wolverine is now es-\nsentially absent from \nthe southern end\nof its European range."

splitted_text = text.split("-\n")

splitted_text.each_with_index do |line, index|
  next_line = splitted_text[index + 1]

  if next_line.present?
    line << next_line[/\w+/] + "\n"
    next_line.sub!(/\w+/, '').strip!
  end
end

splitted_text.join
```

Result

```
"The wolverine is now essentially\nabsent from \nthe southern end\nof its European range."
```

Answer (score 0):

concat the parts of wrapped word and break line after the concatened word

```
text = "The wolverine is now es-\nsentially absent from \nthe southern end\nof its European range."
=> "The wolverine is now es-\nsentially absent from \nthe southern end\nof its European range."

text.gsub(/-\n([^\s]*)\s/,$1+"\n")
=> "The wolverine is now essentially\nabsent from \nthe southern end\nof its European range."
```